vscode latex-workshop "go to definition" in the same pane
Before I reinstalled my PC, when I use LaTeX-workshop in VScode, the left pane is the .tex editor and the right pane is the pdf viewer. If I click "go to definition" on the left pane to go to some sub .tex file (used by "include" or "input"), the referred file opens on the left pane.
After I reinstalled my PC and got my VSCode settings synced from MS cloud, the .tex file opens on the right panel even if I click "go to definition" on the left panel. This is undesired behavior.
Is there a setting to go back to the old behavior?
The closest results I could find is similar to this, which does not really match my case.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
